# How to validate html when u add facebook like box?

Tags: html, validation

Validation Output: there is no attribute "profile_id"

Any solution for html validation?

Comment: also i added <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" xml:lang="en">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using the XFBML method. Did you try to put the XFBML code inside a CDATA delimiter? See http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Answer (score 0):

Facebook are big enough and i suspect smart enough to come up with some type of wrapper that would remove these error - its annoying that any major web presence can create such apps / widgets knowing they will create invalid HTML!!